# Loop through a spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, tkinter, spreadsheet

I made a Python program using tkinter and pandas to select rows and send them by email.

The program let the user decides on which excel file wants to operate;

- then asks on which sheet of that file you want to operate;
- then it asks how many rows you want to select (**using .tail function**);
- then the program is supposed to iterate through rows and read from a cell (within selected rows) the email address;
- then it sends the correct row to the correct address.

**I'm stuck at the iteration process.**

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import smtplib

def invio_mail(my_tailed__df): #the function imports the sliced (.tail) dataframe
    gmail_user = '###'
    gmail_password = '###'
    sent_from = gmail_user
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
    server.ehlo()
    server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)

    list = my_tailed_df

    customers = list['CUSTOMER']
    wrs = list['WR']
    phones = list['PHONE']
    streets = list['STREET']
    cities = list["CITY"]
    mobiles = list['MOBILE']
    mobiles2 = list['MOBILE2']
    mails = list['INST']

    for i in range(len(mails)):
        customer = customers[i]
        wr = wrs[i]
        phone = phones[i]
        street = streets[i]
        city = cities[i]
        mobile = mobiles[i]
        mobile2 = mobiles2[i]
"""
        for i in range(len(mails)):
            if mails[i] == "T138":
                mail = "email_1@gmail.com"
            elif mails[i] == "T139":
                mail = "email_2@gmail.com"
"""
        subject = 'My subject'
        body = f"There you go" \n Name: {customer} \n WR: {wr} \n Phone: {phone} \n Street: {street} \n City: {city} \n Mobile: {mobile} \n Mobile2: {mobile2}"


        email_text = """\
        From: %s
        To: %s
        Subject: %s
    
        %s
        """ % (sent_from, ", ".join(mail), subject, body)
        try:
            server.sendmail(sent_from, [mail], email_text)
            server.close()
            print('Your email was sent!')
        except:
            print("Some error")
```

The program raises a **KeyError: 0** after it enters the for loop, on the first line inside the loop:   `customer = customers[i]`

I know that the commented part (the nested for loop) will raise the same error.

I'm banging my head on the wall, I think i've read and tried everything.

Where's my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things start to go wrong here: `list = my_tailed_df`. In Python [list()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#lists) is a Built-in Type.

However, with `list = my_tailed_df`, you are overwriting the type. You can check this:

```
# before the line:
print(type(list))
<class 'type'>

list = my_tailed_df

# after the line:
print(type(list))
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> # assuming that your df is an actual df!
```

This is bad practice and adds no functional gain at the expense of confusion. E.g. `customers = list['CUSTOMER']` is doing the exact same thing as would `customers = my_tailed_df['CUSTOMER']`, namely creating a pd.Series with the index from my_tailed_df. So, first thing to do, is to get rid of `list = my_tailed_df` and to change all those `list[...]` snippets into `my_tailed_df[...]`.

Next, let's look at your error. `for i in range(len(mails)):` generates `i = 0, 1, ..., len(mails)-1`. Hence, what you are trying to do, is access the pd.Series at the *index* `0, 1` etc. If you get the error `KeyError: 0`, this must simply mean that the index of your original df does not contain this key in the index (e.g. it's a list of IDs or something).

If you don't need the original index (as seems to be the case), you could remedy the situation by resetting the index:

```
my_tailed_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

print(my_tailed_df.index)
# will get you: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=x, step=1)
# where x = len(my_tailed_df)-1 (== len(mails)-1)
```

Implement the reset *before* the line `customers = my_tailed_df['CUSTOMER']` (so, instead of `list = my_tailed_df`), and you should be good to go.

Alternatively, you could keep the original index and change `for i in range(len(mails)):` into  `for i in mails.index:`.

Finally, you could also do `for idx, element in enumerate(mails.index):` if you want to keep track both of the position of the index element (idx) and its value (element).

Comment: Ty so much, I implemented both of your solutions! I fixed the bad practice and I've resetted the index. The iteration is now working properly :)
Plus I've fixed the nested loop by using the .replace method!